# ChangeNotifierProvider For Theming Riverpod

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I would like to change the app theme according to switch button. I am using ChangeNotifier to do that.

```
class ThemesProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  ThemeMode themeMode = ThemeMode.system;
  bool get isDarkMode => themeMode == ThemeMode.dark;
  void changeTheme(bool isOn) {
    themeMode = isOn ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

that's the class that I am using to change the theme.

```
final themesProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider((_) => ThemesProvider());

class MyApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyApp({
    super.key,
  });
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final themeModeState = ref.watch(themesProvider).themeMode;
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: Themes.lightTheme,
      darkTheme: Themes.darkTheme,
      themeMode: themeModeState,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const SignInScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

That is my main file.

```
final themesProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider((_) => ThemesProvider());

class MainScreen extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MainScreen({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final themeModeState = ref.watch(themesProvider);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Try Me"),
        leading: Consumer(
          builder: (context, ref, child) {
            return Switch(
                value: themeModeState.isDarkMode,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  themeModeState.changeTheme(value);
                });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is where I try to change the theme.

```
I/flutter ( 4525): ThemeMode.dark
```

```
I/flutter ( 4525): ThemeMode.light
```

```
I/flutter ( 4525): ThemeMode.dark
```

It seems the function is working fine. I don't know where I made a mistake. Can one of you please help me to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This short example works as expected:

```dart
void main() => runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));

class ThemesProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  ThemeMode themeMode = ThemeMode.system;
  bool get isDarkMode => themeMode == ThemeMode.dark;
  void changeTheme(bool isOn) {
    themeMode = isOn ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

final themesProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider((_) => ThemesProvider());

class MyApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final themeModeState = ref.watch(themesProvider).themeMode;

    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.light(),
      darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
      themeMode: themeModeState,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const MainScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class MainScreen extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MainScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final themeModeState = ref.watch(themesProvider);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Try Me, current: ${themeModeState.themeMode}"),
        leading: Switch(
          value: themeModeState.isDarkMode,
          onChanged: (value) {
            themeModeState.changeTheme(value);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is probably here:

```dart
...
theme: Themes.lightTheme,
darkTheme: Themes.darkTheme,
...
```

Or maybe you declare two different instances of `ThemesProvider()` and this has some effect (I think not)

Comment: It is working because you use only one  
`final themesProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider((_) => ThemesProvider());`
in my case I declared 2 different  themesProvider for each screen. So, it wasn't working.
Thank you for your answer. I understand the problem thanks to you.
There is no problem with  theme and darkTheme.

Answer (score 0):

For `ChangeNotifier` and `StateNotifier`, you should call functions on notifier. e.g.

```
ref.read(yourProvider.notifier).function()
```

So `onChanged` function in `Switch` widget have to changed to following:

```
onChanged: (value) {
  ref.read(themesProvider.notifier).changeTheme(value);
});
```

Remark: You should use `read` instead of `watch` inside onPressed, onChanged and other functions.

It is usually not recommended to use `ChangeNotifier`, but instead use `StateNotifier`, which promotes immutable architecture and makes code more maintainable.

Comment: I change it to StateNotifier as you said. Thank you.